# reactjs state is not being updated when invoked from a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-state-management

here is the context

I am invoking a function `invoked(..)` from another component. Inside `invoked` I setState but the state does not get set. It does not trigger the useEffect nor does it take the updated value in the useInterval.

Below is the code.

Component 1 = `exampleComp.ts`

```
const exampleComp = ({initValue: ExampleProps}) {
  const [params, setParams] = useState<{field1: null | string}> ({field1: null});

  const invoked = (x: string) => {
    console.log("inside invoked"); // this gets printed
    setParams({"field1": x});
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(params); // does not come here :(
  }, [params]);

  const fetchData = {...};

  useInterval(
      () => {
        if (!params.field1 || fetching) return;
        console.log("in interval", params); // does not come here too :(
        fetchData(params.field1);
      },
      params && !fetching ? 5000: null,
    );

    return {invoked, ...}
}
```

Component 2:

```
const newComp  = ({initValue: ExampleProps}) {
  const {invoked, ..} = useExampleComp({...}); //Example comp is the above component.
  useEffect(() => {
    invoked(x);
  }, []);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated! thanks.

Comment: I don't see any components in your code examples. It might be more helpful for you to provide more complete code and properly formatted and readable examples. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Shouldn't your custom hook also be called `useExampleComp`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the component was unmounting too early. This happens when the scope of the component is too narrow.

If you have a similar problem, try logging the component to see if this is indeed happening.